# When using multiple constant current drivers for High Power RGB LEDs, connect Vo- together?

Tags: led, driver, rgb

I'm using a set of three [Mean Well HLG-60A-C350AB](https://www.proconnecting.de/media/pdf/7f/64/7b/HLG-80H-C-SPEC.pdf) in order to drive a string of 48 [no-name high power RGB LEDs](http://www.ledlight-components.com/photo/ledlight-components/document/14230/DL-HP05RGBC-1.5W.pdf).

I chose these drivers because they provide an easy way to regulate the constant between 200mA and 350mA, in order to compensate for brightness deviations between the three colours. I chose to use three of them in order to individually control the RGB channels.

The drivers are fed from the same AC voltage source. The LED brightness is controlled by PWM from an Arduino Mega stepped up to 10V.

**Should the Vo- of the drivers be connected together?**

---

[image: picture of three drivers]

Comment: You are considering connecting the output 0 V lines together but you need to watch what's happening on the PWM circuit too and to ensure that the high current doesn't take a path through the control signal wiring. If the input signals are isolated from the output you should be OK for them to share their 0 V independently of the outputs. See http://lednique.com/power-supplies/dimmable-mains-psu-control/ for an explanation of the PWM circuitry - assuming its the same type on your controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT after OP clarifications

Basically, you suggest to to the following :

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhO9Rn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Yes, it should work, BUT you can see that the current of the 3 channels flows through one single Vo- wire from the strip to the power supply. It may, or may not exceed what it can safely sustain... But if the current on each channel is kept within the specifications of the strip, it should work as expected

The drawback here is the high current into the wire that comes back from the LED strip. And it's also a single point of failure. If it breaks, all LED are affected. And if the current if high enough on one channel, the small resistance of the wire may induce a variation on intensity into the 2 other channels. ( if you use small wires for instance)

The second suggestion is :

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyCv32.png)</sup>
The advantage of this is a complete isolation. Not a single point of failure.
The drawback is the cost of the wiring.

Comment: These are constant current supplies, designed to drive LEDs directly- no resistors are needed.

Comment: @Frog, Good catch! I haven't checked the PSU. But anyway, it doesn't mean the strip does not include resistors. I have plethora of LED strips at home that are meant to be plugged to a fixed voltage initially.
They will work perfectly with a current controlled PSU at the expense of some efficiency due to the power dissipation of the useless resistors...
I have no idea what kind of strip the OP owns.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation. The LEDs are no-name-brand 6-pin 1W-per-channel RGB LEDs. They are each on an individual PCB, mounted on a large aluminium heat sink (indeed without resistors, as Frog suggests). 

The Vo- would be connected together with a 20 awg or higher wire so that should sustain the maximum 1,05A with ease.

Comment: Considering my clarification above. Would it be preferable to connect the Vo- of the different channels together or not? What positive or negative effects would it have?

Comment: There should be no problem except that all of the return current will flow down one conductor; provided that the conductor is adequate you should be fine.